# HTML element right-aligned to edge of sibling centered element

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like to get a specific layout using CSS, as follows, and I'm not sure if it's possible.  There's some text inside a div that is centered.  Underneath, there is another div with text inside; what I'd like to do is to right-align this text so that its right edge is flush with the right edge of the text above it.

Using CSS, I have no idea how to do this.  Clearly the following approach will not work, because the sub-header will right-align to the container.  But is there any trick to accomplish the alignment I want?

<s><div style='text-align: center;'>This is some headline text</div></s>

<div style='text-align: right;'>Sub-header text</div>

**Note:** Strong preference is for straight CSS (no Javascript if possible).

**Note #2:** I'm not stuck with the above HTML.  I can use any markup that accomplishes the described alignment.

Comment: Are you stuck with that HTML?

Comment: not possible with the HTML markup you have

Comment: @thirtydot no, I'm happy with any HTML that will accomplish the alignment.

Comment: There appears to be some really clever stuff [here (stackoverflow.com)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript) about calculating the width of text in an element.

Comment: @ZoltanToth Is there any markup I could use to get what I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> @thirtydot no, I'm happy with any HTML that will accomplish the
>   alignment.

Try this then: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/nU9Cj/

```
<div style='text-align: center'>
    <span style="position: relative">This is some headline text
        <span style='position: absolute; top: 100%; right: 0; font-weight: bold'>Sub-header text</span>    
    </span>
</div>
```

You probably want to add some `padding-bottom` to the `div`, to make up for the height lost by the subheader being absolutely positioned.

Comment: I just had this exact problem, and greatly appreciate the solution. One extra note: the position:relative span needs to not be a div, because a div expands to take up extra horizontal room, shoving the subheading off to the right side of the screen. (Or at least, the position:relative element needs to not be display:block.)